# Compare two array And Store in another array with matched and unmatched as 0

Tags: php

I found some solutions on google but they are not fulfilling my requirement.
 I have an array,

```
$current_week = self::CurrentWeekDateRange($s_date, $e_date);
```

it is giving me result:

```
    [0] => 2016-09-06
    [1] => 2016-09-07
    [2] => 2016-09-08
    [3] => 2016-09-09
    [4] => 2016-09-10
    [5] => 2016-09-11
    [6] => 2016-09-12
    [7] => 2016-09-13
    [8] => 2016-09-14
    [9] => 2016-09-15
    [10] => 2016-09-16
    [11] => 2016-09-17
    [12] => 2016-09-18
```

now My Next array is like this: **user log** **$return** a array

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-08
            [total] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-13
            [total] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-14
            [total] => 400
        )
```

No i have , 3 user means it print 3 times user log.
So what i want is i want to match **date_log** to above my first array, 
If its matches it will give it will get store in another array and if not match then it will store 0.
My problem i am using two loops ant it is printing **loop1 * loop2** times value but i want only **$current_week** times values

I tried like this:

```
$current_week = self::CurrentWeekDateRange($s_date, $e_date);

          $i = 0;

          foreach ($current_week as $day){
              foreach ($returns as $return) {
                    if($day == $return['date_log']){
                        $array_total_hours[$i]['total'] = $return['total'];
                        $array_total_hours[$i]['date_log'] = $return['date_log'];
                    }
                    else {
                        $array_total_hours[$i]['date_log'] = $return['date_log'];
                        $array_total_hours[$i]['total'] = 0;
                    }

                    $i++;
              }
          }

print( $array_total_hours);
```

I want my result like this:

```
  [2016-09-06] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-06
            [total] => 0
        )

    [2016-09-07] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-07
            [total] => 30
        )

    [2016-09-08] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-08
            [total] => 400
        )
    [2016-09-09] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-09
            [total] => 0
        )
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
  [2016-09-18] => Array
        (
            [date_log] => 2016-09-18
            [total] => 0
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the job.

```
$current_week = self::CurrentWeekDateRange($s_date, $e_date); 

$finalResult = array();
foreach ($current_week as $date) {
    $finalResult[$date] = array('date_log' => $date, 'total' => 0);
}

$dates = array_keys($finalResult);
// not sure where this one comes from
$nextArray = array(
     array('date_log' => '2016-09-08', 'total' => 15),
     array('date_log' => '2016-09-13', 'total' => 30)
     );

foreach ($nextArray as $return) {
    $record = array('date' => '', 'total' => 0);
    if (in_array($return['date'], $dates)) {
        $finalResult[$return['date']]['total'] = $return['total'];
    }
}
```

Comment: thx... i replaced some lines for more clarity - i guess you did the same on your side.

Answer (score 1):

okey working with your solution it will work like this:

```
$current_week = self::CurrentWeekDateRange($s_date, $e_date);

      $i = 0;

      foreach ($current_week as $day){
          $value = 0;
          $date = $return
          foreach ($returns as $return) {
                if($day == $return['date_log']){
                    $value = $return['total'];
                 break;
                }
           }

           $array_total_hours[$i]['total'] = $value;
           $array_total_hours[$i]['date_log'] = $date;

           $i++;

      }

      print( $array_total_hours);
```

You only have to assing the total value once per $current_week, not for every possible log.